# Scattering to more nodes than there is data

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

What happens if I call `MPI::Scatter` and there are more nodes in the communicator than there is data?

Suppose I have a 4 × 4 array and I'm sending one row to every processor, but I have 8 processors. What happens? Will rank 0 – 3 receive data and rank 4 – 7 get nothing?

Comment: `MPI_Scatterv` sends the exactly same amount of data to each rank. If there are more ranks than data to pass, the function will probably read past the buffer and either send junk or crash. Use `MPI_Scatterv` instead.

Comment: @HristoIliev I guess the first time you write `MPI_Scatterv`, it should have been `MPI_Scatter` instead.

Comment: True, I've meant the one without the `-v`.